# awk: regex not matching

Tags: regex, awk

i have the following command with awk. which is not matching the regex. it ouputs nothing

```
$ echo 800x900| awk '/\d+/{print $0}'
```

whereas

```
$ echo 800x900| awk '/800/{print $0}'
800x900
```

My regex `\d+` is proper. it matches `800`. https://regex101.com/r/xV8eB7/1

Comment: the escape sequence `\d` doesn't exist in awk (that uses ERE *Extended Regular Expression*), use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` instead.

Comment: it works. how to know more such difference between awks regex and normal regex

Comment: "normal regex" exists only in your mind, each regex engine has a proper syntax or set of features. Make a search about ERE to know the details about awk patterns.

Comment: i dont know why it marked duplicate. the answer in the duplicate question does not mention about [[:digit:]]